# How do I network Windows XP Home and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I would like to share files between my Windows XP Home system and my new Windows 7 system. I am using AT&T Uverse with the Uverse wireless router. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: See this...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that both computers are connected to the Uverse router with two ethernet (RJ45) cables. Your best bet would be set up a shared folder or partition on one of the machines. I'd reccomend the Windows 7 Machine.

- Create a folder
- Right-click on it and choose properties
- Choose the "Sharing" tab
- Click on the "advanced sharing" button (may prompt for UAC)
- Check the "share this folder" checkbox
- Choose a share name (for example "shared")
- Click on "Permissions" and set everybody to everything (ONLY IF you have access to the network though)
- Click "Ok" then "close"

Providing that you can ping each computer you will be able to access this folder from the other machine by typing in \pcname\share in Windows Explorer.

By 10 months in you may have found a solution.

Comment: don't forget to enable network-sharing in network-center (don't know the english name of that) and disable or configure the firewall.